# nonparametric intensity function estimation with more than two covariates

Tags: statistics, spatstat

In package "Spatstat", function "rho2hat" can estimate intensity function with two covariates but in most cases the number of environmental and ecological covariates are more than two. My question is if there any function which we can employ in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no analogue of `rho2hat` for more than two covariates. In principle it is possible to do more covariates, but it would be very fiddly and not something we plan to ever do in `spatstat`.